# How to pass info from control to event at Runtime

Tags: c#

I'm creating buttons by code inside a FlowLayoutPanel and I can't create a click event for each one of the created buttons. I need some help cause i'm stuck on this.

Comment: You don't need an event for each one. Just create a sinlge OnClick handler in the codebehind with sender and args parameters. Then call this from your markup page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, [Manage controls at Runtime](http://code-in-action.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-adddelete-controls-at-runtime.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can just subscribe to each button's [Click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) as you create them.

For example:

```
Button newButton = new Button();
// Setup button...
newButton.Click += this.ClickHandler;
```

Then, somewhere else:

```
private void ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // Do something here
}
```

The other, potentially more elegant, option would be to bind the Button's [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx) to an ICommand.  You could also set it's [CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx) in order to pass additional, button specific, information.